Connect VPS Server with my mysql database
I have hostinger VPS server and there I uploaded the node.js code with all its necessary modules. But when I try to connect with database using GET API, It gives error

{   "success": false,   "message": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'my_vps_ip' (using password: YES"}

But in localhost it is working perfectly and fetching data correctly..
Anyone can help please ?

{   "success": false,   "message": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'my_vps_ip' (using password: YES"}


What operating system are you using?

If you are using a Red Hat derivative such as AlmaLinux or Rocky Linux, you need to add the MySQL port to firewalld.

Unfortunately, no, we cannot help, as you are the only person, who possibly know the correct mysql user name and password. The error message is very explicit and it means that you provided incorrect user name or password, or your mysql user does not have access to the requested resource.

@kurniadi445 access denied error message means that the OP's application successfully connected to mysql, just could not authenticate with the mysql user or the mysql user does not have access to the requested resource. Nothing to do with port being blocked.
